# FileSystem.CopyFile throws "File not found" even if the file is present

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, copy

I thought this would be simple but it obviously isn't...

I'm trying to copy a file in the AppData folder - specifically the templates folder:

```
Dim path As String
path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.templates)
path = path & "\Normal.dotm"

My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(path, "c:\test\normal.dotm", True)
```

The code above throws the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\EAZIE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\Normal.dotm'.

I know the file is there as I can move it manually. I can run the code on other files perfectly fine.

I've also tried running the program with administrative rights.

Comment: Are you sure the file is in that folder and not `C:\Users\EAZIE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`?  Note the extra "Windows" in your path.

Comment: Did you try capitalizing Templates in Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.templates)? When I use visual studio it won't allow me to type templates as lower-case but maybe that's not the case with you

Comment: To confirm Mark's suggestion, Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates points to users\name\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\windows\templates while the Normal.dotm file is found in users\name\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\templates

Comment: cheers Mark after you pointing this i out i realised (Environment.SpecialFolder.templates) goes to far down - not to where i needed to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks guys for pointing this out the Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates did not point to the folder i thought at first

Are you sure the file is in that folder and not C:\Users\EAZIE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates? Note the extra "Windows" in your path. – Mark

To confirm Mark's suggestion, Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates points to users\name\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\windows\templates while the Normal.dotm file is found in users\name\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\templates – Dalton D